# Why are wc -m and wc -c different?

Tags: character-encoding, locale, wc

As a C programmer, I was surprised to see that `wc -c` (which count the number of bytes), and `wc -m` (which counts the number of characters) output very different results for a long, text file of mine. I had always been told that `sizeof(char)` is 1 byte.

```
qdii@nomada ~/Documents $ wc -c sentences.csv
102990983 sentences.csv
qdii@nomada ~/Documents $ wc -m sentences.csv
89023123 sentences.csv
```

Any explanation?

Comment: See @rici's answer below... you've got your -m and -c flags backwards in your question (c = bytes, m = characters)... your example output is correct, though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `char` type in C is one byte, but it's intended for ASCII characters; there are [variable-width encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding) like UTF-8 that can take up many bytes per character. `wc` uses the `mbrtowc(3)` function to decode multibyte sequences, depending on the locale set by the `LC_CTYPE` environment variable. If you set the locale properly, you should get the same result for all cases. For example:

```
qdii@nomada ~/Documents $ LC_CTYPE="C" wc -m sentences.csv
102990983 sentences.csv
```

Answer (score 18):

At a guess,

1. Your locale uses UTF-8 encoding, and
2. About 10% of your file consists of characters which require more than one octet to encode into UTF-8.

By the way, from `man wc`:

```
   -c, --bytes
          print the byte counts

   -m, --chars
          print the character counts
```

Answer (score 2):

**Minimal example**

Consider the Unicode character "é" known as "[LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm)", which is an 'e' with an [acute accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent) used in several European languages.

Its UTF-8 encoding is two bytes long "0xc3 0xa9".

With that in mind we see:

```
printf '\xc3\xa9' | LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 wc -c
printf '\xc3\xa9' | LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 wc -m
printf '\xc3\xa9' | LC_CTYPE=C wc -c
printf '\xc3\xa9' | LC_CTYPE=C wc -m
```

outputs:

```
2
1
2
2
```

So we understand as explained at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/51948/32558 that to get the correct UTF-8 count we need both `wc -m` and `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`.

In my system, the outcome is the same if I use the input method to type a literal é:

```
printf 'é' | LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 wc -c
```

Tested on Ubuntu 21.04.